# No more error squiggles in VScode? There are no such things like C_Cpp in setting (JSON)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just noticed that VScode (and Insider as well) doesn't provide error squiggle anymore. I've been looking around Stackoverflow and Google to find the solution, and most of them say "Find File > Preferences > Settings > type "squiggle" in the search box > set "C_Cpp: Error Squiggles" to enabledIfIncludesResolve or Enable".
However, there are no such things like C_Cpp in settings (JSON).

It worked fine up until several weeks. Has MS changed it on purpose?

Version: 1.79.2
Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:57:04.379Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Comment: what language are you working with / observing this for? provide example code that you expect to produce problems, and show where you expect to see them.

Comment: Mainly Python, but I'm also working with Javascript and Flutter occasionally. Whatever I made, VScode doesn't show me the error squiggles even though I input a ridiculous code.
For instance, say I input the following code:
'''
import xaoeirfwoieurfjwoe4urfuiwotf
print('oh my godness (
'''
This is definitely a wrong code. But VScode doesn't show the error squiggles at all.

Comment: 1) is there any syntax highlighting for well-formed code? is the language mode appropriately set? 2) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.

Comment: I guess the syntax highlighting works fine as it looks colorful and the language mode appropriately set. Updated the post with Help: About.

Comment: are there any entries in the PROBLEMS panel

Comment: Nope. That's why I thought it's strange. Compared to Pycharm, VScode seems not giving you so much info.